# Finding a prime number using a **custom** Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I would like to pass an array of `numbers` to my `is_prime?` method and return if the numbers are valid or not. I do not want to use:

```
require 'prime'
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
Hash[a.zip(a.map(&Prime.method(:prime?)))]
```

This is learning experience. My current code is only outputing the first number in the array. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
def is_prime?(*nums)
i = 2
    nums.each do |num|
        while i < num
            is_divisible = ((num % i) == 0)
                if is_divisible == false
                    x = "#{num}: is NOT a prime number." #false
               else
                    x = "#{num}: is a prime number." #true
                end

            i +=1   
        end
        return x
    end
end

puts is_prime?(27,13,42)
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement in your each loop. It will always exit the loop. Also, your `is_divisible` statement makes no sense, why store the boolean in a variable then test it? Just move `num % i == 0` into your if statement condition.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks I have updated the code as per your suggestion, however the logic is still incorrect as I am not getting the desired output. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return your results in the same format as your usage of the prime library with the same logic as your custom function:

```
def is_prime?(*nums)
  nums.each_with_object({}) do |num, hsh|
    hsh[num] = num > 1 && 2.upto(num - 1).none? { |i| num % i == 0 }
  end
end

puts is_prime?(27,13,42)
# => {27=>false, 13=>true, 42=>false}
```

Since you mention this is just for learning, I'm assuming you know that a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a better way to go for this than brute force iteration.

If you want an explanation of how the above code works or further help understanding why your current code doesn't, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning in the loop.

A few bugs in your method:

```
def is_prime?(*nums)
   nums.each do |num|
      return false if num == 1
      next if num == 2 # 2 is the only even prime
      i = 2  # needs to be reset for each num
      while i < num 
        return false if num % i == 0  # num is not prime
        i += 1   
      end
   end
   true # We'll reach here only if all the numbers are prime
end
```

Comment: ROFL! Easy karma for you rohit89!

Comment: If I move the `return` outside of the loop. It returns undefined. Additionally the code seems to always return `false`.

Comment: You want the method to return true if all the numbers are prime otherwise false?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your code is only returning for the `first` index in the `array`. *Your edit is also giving the same result.*

Comment: Not sure I understand. If the first number in the array is not a prime, it will return false.

Comment: @rohit89: OP means `nums.each`, but to your credit, is_prime? Should nly accept a single argument. Anything else is not very sane (except, incidentally, the way you implemented it.)...

Comment: If you want to implement an array, change the *nums argument to just 'nums'; though if you do it this way, you must supply an array (even if that array only holds one value).